# SailsJS : add a second DB adapter?

Tags: neo4j, sails.js

So there's an existing sails app that uses MongoDB at the moment.
I need to add a new service to this which needs to work with Neo4j.

is it possible to configure the app to work with two different adapters?

the sails version of the app is 0.12.13

Please advise!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done: https://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm

We struggled to add 2 adapters of the same kind, e.g. 2 MongoDB adapters, though.

Comment: I found that creating a driver instance and adding it to the sails namespace worked conveniently .. it also meant that I can't make use of models. but this is fine for my use case.